# How to print a log in Kotlin KSP Processor?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-symbol-processing

In [Kotlin KSP](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/ksp-overview.html), I try to debug the processor

```
internal class ListedProcessor(
    private val fileGenerator: FileWriter,
) : SymbolProcessor {

    override fun process(resolver: Resolver): List<KSAnnotated> {

        val listedFunctions: Sequence<KSFunctionDeclaration> =
            resolver.findAnnotations(Listed::class)
        val arrayedFunctions: Sequence<KSFunctionDeclaration> =
            resolver.findAnnotations(Arrayed::class)

        return (listedFunctions + arrayedFunctions).filterNot { it.validate() }.toList()
    }
}
```

I try to use `println` but don't know where the output goes to. How can I dump out log for Kotlin KSP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the conversation in Kotlin Slack, please use the [`KSPLogger`](https://github.com/google/ksp/blob/7dc1d7421a38b4f8490bb5eba5d3e3f6decac6b4/api/src/main/kotlin/com/google/devtools/ksp/processing/KSPLogger.kt) to perform logging. For example:

```
logger.warn(allFiles.toList().toString())
```

You can get a handle on the `KSPLogger` through the `environment` parameter in the `create` function of your `SymbolProcessorProvider`:

```
class TestProcessorProvider : SymbolProcessorProvider {
    override fun create(environment: SymbolProcessorEnvironment): SymbolProcessor {
        return TestProcessor(environment.codeGenerator, environment.logger)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David. Where does it log out to? I try to run using ./gradlew but not seeing it shown on the terminal.

Comment: Thanks. I manage to see the Warning and Error. But not the Info yet. Where can I set the `--verbose` in IntelliJ or Android Studio setting? I post a StackOverflow on this question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75601653/how-to-set-verbose-in-intellij-android-studio-for-ksp-debugging-purposes Thanks!