# How to set --verbose in IntelliJ (Android Studio) for KSP debugging purposes?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin-symbol-processing

As shared in https://stackoverflow.com/a/75441869/3286489, we have a way to print log out for KSP compilation.

However, the print out only shows WARNING and ERROR. If I want to have INFO, I'll need to set `--verbose`.

The question is, where or how can we set the `--verbose` in IntelliJ (Android Studio), so that in compilation, it will print the verbose log out (other than Warnings and Errors)?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is gradlew assemble --info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I can set it in

Preference --> Compiler --> Commandline-Options

And write `--info` to it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Edit run configuration and add `--verbose` to gradle command.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9GoU.png)